# Capture Facebook content to a Sharepoint library

Tags: rss

Does anyone know if it's possible to capture Facebook content to a SharePoint library.  By this I don't just mean view a Facebook feed in a web part which seems to be what most people do. I want to capture the content in some readable  form and eventually then send that content to a record center that I will set up. Is this feasible or am I dreaming again? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Its feasible, but that would be a lot of work. First you would probably need to set up a custom BCS connection that hits a Facebook web service or RSS feed. Then create a facebook content type(s) that is Posts, etc. How often do you want to query Facebook for content? You will have to pick apart the data and put the data where it needs to go, in specific lists. The record center should be easy to set up, just set up an information management policy to move a content type to a record center.